# Hide rows in different sheets within the same worksheet when check box is selected

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have a check box in sheet 1 called "Travel" which hides rows 30:31 as below:

```
Private Sub CheckBox6_Click()
    [30:31].EntireRow.Hidden = Not CheckBox6.Value
End Sub
```

I also want to hide row 3 and rows 13:21 of another sheet within the same spreadsheet called "Look up" when this same check box is selected.

Does anyone know the code for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood the name of the OTHER sheet is "Look up". Then try this in your `CheckBox6_Click` sub:

```
 Sheets("Look up").[3:3].EntireRow.Hidden = Not CheckBox1.Value
 Sheets("Look up").[13:21].EntireRow.Hidden = Not CheckBox1.Value
```

Comment: I just had to change checkbox1.value to checkbox6.value for it to work. what if I wanted it to unhide instead?

Comment: If you want the checkbox to behave the other way round just remove the word 'Not' from the commands.

Comment: Thank you again. What if I also want to change the text in cell B8 from "info from feed file" to "estimated figures" when ticked?